# Is there a way to rewrite this url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all urls like these:

```
www.example.com/blog.php?id=29
```

to urls like these:

```
www.example.com/blog/29/this-is-a-blogpost
```

Where "This is a blogpost" is the title stored in the database.

Is there a way to rewrite these urls in this way ?

Comment: stackoverflow does a similar thing I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well mod_rewrite canot query your database and pull the title for the provided id from a DB table.

You'll need to pass id to a server side code (like a php script) in order to fetch & display title.

For ex look at the SO URL for this question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239887/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-this-url` where it is passing both id and title. So you can have friendly URLs like:

`http://www.example.com/blog/29/this-is-a-blogpost`

If you decide to go by my suggestion then here is the code you will need in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /content.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Then in your `content.php`:

```
<?php
   $id    = $_GET['id'];
   $title = $_GET['title'];

   $dbTitle = // get title from Database query using $id
   ...
   if ($title != $dbTitle) {
      // redirect with 301 to correct /blog/<id>/<title> page
      header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
      header('Location: /blog/' . $id . '/' . $dbTitle);
      exit;
   }
   // rest of your script
?>
```

Comment: Thanks :D Is this the solution adopted by stackoverflow ?

Comment: SO definitely has similar logic in place. You can try removing title from this question and it will be appended by a URL redirect.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is obviously impossible: the second url you want to redirect to contains data that is not present (known) in the original request. Where should that data come from inside the redirection process?

The other way round certainly *is* possible and often done.