# 301 redirect in StackOverflow. How does it works?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, http-status-code-301

Let's take, for instance, the url of this question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306229/301-redirect-in-stackoverflow-how-does-it-works
```

If i change something in the final part of the URL, making it like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306229/301-r
```

I get a 301 message and i'm redirected EXACTLY to the first URL i wrote.

This is reaaally SEO Friendly, IMHO. The question is: how did they do it? Is it possible to achieve it via .htaccess or there's another way to do it? In this case which way?

I'm not really expert, but it looks impossible to reach via htaccess...it looks more like

1. I get the post ID from the URL
2. I check the Database to see if the titles are equal
3. If they're not, i rewrite the URL and send a 301 response

Comment: +1, a very good question... If engineerers of SO give us some helps.

Comment: This is pretty simple actually. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17240067/548225

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to rewrite this url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239887/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-this-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming they route the request through a page that checks the database for the seo-title.

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?$ routepage.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ routepage.php?id=$1&title=$2 [R=301,L]
```

And a file `routepage.php`

```
$page = getSeoTitleFromDatabase( $_GET['id'] );
if( $page != $_GET['page'] ) {
  header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
  header( "Locations: /questions/" . $_GET['id'] . "/" . $page );
}
//Do whatever...
```

I am not aware of a way of checking the database with `.htaccess` or `mod_rewrite`.